# Why is the "edit" link for a question not enabled?

Tags: support

When I view [this new question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/31490/14510), the *edit* link is not enabled.  Why?  (I want to fix the spelling in the title.)

Answer (score 4):

It has an outstanding suggested edit. In this case you can't edit the post until the edit has been approved or rejected.